# Не удается подписать commit gpg ключем через vs code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, git-commit, gpg

Я сделал все по документации github и после попытки сделать commit через интерфейс vs code я получаю эту ошибку:

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Я пробовал несколько раз создавать новые ключи и заново им присваивать, также в настройках vs code поставил галочку с signing commit. Но ничего не меняется, ошибка остается та же.
Пока не пробовал с другими ide, но мне предподчительно исправить эту ошибку именно в vs code. Когда я делал commit вручную, тогда все удачно прошло.

Comment: "*Когда я делал commit вручную, тогда все удачно прошло.*" - ¿чем он отличается от предоставленного в вопросе?

Comment: @user7860670 не используя интерфейс, в консоле.

Comment: ¿Ну а еще чем? ¿Какие переменные окружения, какая рабочая папка?

Comment: @user7860670 я попробовал отследить, что делает после commit. gpg --status-fd=2 он выполняют эту команду, а это команда выдает ошибку: 
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: can't open 'C9255AC679B0BD13'